# JS reset function for 2 clipboards

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

Great day, I would like to ask for some advise please, im really new to html and css as well as java and putting all of them together is a bit hard for me so, i'm hoping for some advise.

I recently created a form, though i couldn't figure out how to reset all the function, like resetting the contain to its original form after im done copying it.

please the my codes and let me know what i can do. your help is greatly appreciated.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
/* Some Generic styles */
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #023378;
  line-height: 0.5;
  background-color:#1E334F;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0.5em auto 0.5em;
  color: #71A4EB;
}
textarea,
button {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
textarea {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em auto 0.5em;
  background: #CAD6E6;
  resize: vertical;
}
[id="cleared"] {
  margin-top: 4em;
}
textarea:focus {
  border-color: #8fa423;
}
button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 0.835em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.125em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #3F71B6;
  background: #7DA9E6;
  transition: background .275s;
}
button:hover,
button:focus {
  background: #5275A5;
}

p {
  margin-top: 3.25em;
  font-size: .825em;
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: .01em
}
</style>

<h1>SH!N</h1>
<body>

<textarea id="to-copy" cols="80" rows="25" spellcheck="false">
SESA
Caller's Name:
Call back number:
Email Address:
Related case #s (case history):
Location, remote/hotel/office:

Application Name: 
Number of Users Affected: Number of Users Affected: (Single User / Less than 5 users / 5 or more users)

What is the issue/problem:
When did the issue/problem begin:
Login id:  
Error message (if any):
When was the last time it worked properly:
Have there been any changes to your PC since the last time it worked properly:
Have you changed your password recently:

Troubleshooting steps (detailed):

Additional Detail (links, screen shots etc.. :
</textarea><br>

<button id="copy" type="button">Copy<span class="copiedtext"aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
<textarea id="text" cols="80" rows="8" >
Resolution:


A - problem:
B - cause:
C - actions:
D - resolution:
</textarea><br>
<button onclick="copy()">Copy</button><br>

<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
var toCopy  = document.getElementById( 'to-copy' ),
    btnCopy = document.getElementById( 'copy' );

btnCopy.addEventListener( 'click', function(){
  toCopy.select();
  
  if ( document.execCommand( 'copy' ) ) {
      btnCopy.classList.add( 'copied' );
    
      var temp = setInterval( function(){
        btnCopy.classList.remove( 'copied' );
        clearInterval(temp);
      }, 600 );
    
  } else {
    console.info( 'document.execCommand went wrong…' )
  }
  
  return false;
} );

function copy () {
 var text = document.getElementById('text');
 var range = document.createRange();

 range.selectNode(text);
 window.getSelection().addRange(range);
 document.execCommand('copy');
}

</SCRIPT>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a form, you should not use textarea (or using it only as a part of a form, for instance to make a comment in a blog)

If you want to make a form, you must use form tag

```
   <form id="myForm">Caller's name <input type="text" name="callerName"> ...  </form>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

And then if you want to reset it, inside javascript :

`document.getElementById("myForm").reset();`

Your form does have id "myForm", you select this element and use reset() function on it which work on form.

PS: You should put your style in a CSS file and your script in a JS file.

EDIT :

If you want to copy it :

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
var targetForm = document.getElementById('targetForm');
targetForm.innerHTML = myForm.innerHTML;
```

Offcourse you need to have a form tag with id set to targetForm.

Comment: thank you for responding, yes you are correct indeed though im not sure on how i'd be able to copy everything with 1 click,

i need to be able to copy the question and the answer.. like 
Name: SHIN
EMAIL: dhasiud@example.com

something like that.. im still learning though :D

Comment: You can do that with the code i gave you in my EDIT, it'll copy everything inside <form> </form>.

Or you can for instance put your question in span with a specific class and get an array of it with document.getElementsByClass("question")
and doing same thing puting class "answer" for <input> and other element of your form.